# Is there a way to fetch item from a particular index from lists within a dictionary(values)

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a dictionary with key names as step1, step2, step3 accordingly, and each key has associated values that are list with say 5 items in each one of them.
My requirement is to get average of each item in the dictionary:

```
mydict = {
    'step1': [0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.96, 0.94],
    'step2': [0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94], 
    'step3': [0.92, 0.86, 0.98, 0.92, 0.94]
}
```

As hard code I can write this- but I want to make it more dynamic:

```
avg_each_item1 = (
    mydict['step1'][0]
    + mydict['step2'][0]
    + mydict['step3'][0]
    + mydict['step4'][0]
    + mydict['step5'][0]
) / 5
```

Any quick tips on it are highly appreciated

Comment: ``sum(v[0] for _ , v in mydict.items()) / len(mydict)`` ?

Comment: Thanks @sushanth works like a charm!
Thank you to everyone who has contributed, will surely look more into numpy as well

Answer (score 1):

Please Have A Look At This Snippet Does This Solve Your Prop?

```py
import numpy as np  # Make Sure You Have 'numpy' installed

mydict = {'step1': [0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.96, 0.94], 'step2': [
    0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94], 'step3': [0.92, 0.86, 0.98, 0.92, 0.94]}

for k, v in mydict.items():
    print("Average For", k, ":", np.average(mydict[k]))  # Calculating The Average for each step.
```

Hope so this snippet would help.

*Happy Coding!*

Comment: Yes, i knew that and did it on purpose because numpy is a well know and a faster lib then any other libs @HarshitSaini

Comment: By the way OP has coded it, I don't think this is what he is looking for. See the comment by @sushanth.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the size of each list is known in advance you can do it in one line:

```
>>> [sum([mydict[j][i] for j in mydict])/len(mydict.keys()) for i in range(5)]
[0.9280000000000002, 0.892, 0.9640000000000001, 0.932, 0.9399999999999998]
```